# jhipster, with micro service, gateway (logstash) did not write metrics to elasticsearch

Tags: jhipster

gateway logstashAppender is no work , but  consoleAppender It's normal

[image]

Comment: Please don't use images for text, just copy/paste and please clarify your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the Kafka dependency and feel like compatibility issues

Comment: This is not an answer, you should have edited your question.